# Errors in Frontend and Backend after Update to 10.4.6

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

In fairness, I would first like to say that I have already posted this problem on https://talk.typo3.org/.

TYPO3 version: 10.4.6
Web server: Apache
PHP version: 7.2.10
Database (default): MySQL 5.7.24
Application context: Production
Operating system: Linux 4.19.44-gentoo-mw1

Problem:
Since the update to version 10.4.6 I get for pages to be displayed in the backend:
The requested page is missing a valid site configuration
and in the frontend:
Page Not Found The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: The requested page does not exist
The "View Webpage" button does not respond at all.
I suspect that the TypoScript script no longer fits the latest version. It has not changed since then, but is now making this mistake.

I'm thankful for any help!
Regards, Strawk

Comment: talk.typo3.org is a feedback to news articles. You get more help here or in Slack channels, see https://typo3.org/help

Answer (score 2):

'site configuration' is not only typoscript. in former versions you needed a domain record. in newer TYPO3 it is a yaml-configuration.

But you can edit it's content in the Backend without knowing the structur.
There is an BE module `SITE MANAGEMENT` -> `Sites`
There you need to configure your domain, language, routing, ...